# String reversal recursively

Tags: c, string

Ok, i wrote 2 versions of this program. But im looking for the best solution - the most simple and fast one.

This is my solution but i was told that this solution is O(n*n) slower, which i dont know what really means. I was also told i could fasten it by breaking it into 2 functions, could anyone help me doing this?

```
void reverse3(char s[])
{
     int l;
     int i;

     l = strlen(s);
     if(l > 1)
     {
          reverse3(s + 1);

          for(i = 1; i < l; i++)
          {
              int temp = s[i-1];
              s[i-1] = s[i];
              s[i] = temp;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Remember the simplest doesn't have to be the fastest, and vice versa.  I predict the best answer for you will be the simplest with the best algorithmic time complexity (big-oh notation, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), which means O(n) here (aka linear).

Comment: Stack overflow shouldn't be used for homework help.

Comment: This isnt homework, im studying K&R2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should swap the outermost bytes, i.e., i=1 and j=(l-1), then i=2, j=(l-2), etc. until i <= (j-1) (in other words, until either i=j, for an even number of characters, or i=j-1, for an odd number).

That will perform in O(n).

Recursion isn't necessary, and "breaking it into two functions" doesn't seem necessary either IMHO.

Ok, read your edit about this being part of the assignment.

In this case, you *do* need two functions to, as Jimmy said, preserve the parameter list of your "main" function.

The second function would be something like:

```
void swapRecursive(char[s], i, l) {      
   if(i >= (l-1) { return; } // no more swapping needed
   char t = s[i];
   s[i] = (l-i);
   s[l-i] = t;
   swapRecurse(s, i+1, l);
   }
```

Please excuse my rusty C, I live in C#, VB.NET, and JavaScript now, some of the details escape me.

Also, I may or may not have left a bug in there, since this *is* homework. ;)

Comment: breaking it into 2 functions is probably for preserving the method signature, and you can put the strlen call in the nonrecursive function.

Comment: Purposeful bugs help no one. Especially since you are rusty enough to make it worth mentioning, how is he, an admitted beginner student, supposed to distinguish what is a bug and what isn't?

Comment: Its ok, i think i know what he means. Please take a look at the function i wrote to see if that's what you had in mind though!

Comment: And no, im not a student. Im still in highschool, self studying from K&R.

Comment: Actually, HS is full of students last I checked. :) You may not be studying C in HS, but you're still a "student" in the sense of learning the language without having seriously applied it yet.

Comment: Good on him, getting a head start. He'll be leaps and bounds ahead of his peers when he actually starts learning this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
void swapRecursive(char s[], int i, int len) {      

   if(i >= len/2+1) 
       return;

   char t = s[i];
   s[i] = s[len-i];
   s[len-i] = t;

   swapRecursive(s, i+1, len);
}

void reverse3(char s[])
{
     int i = 0;

     swapRecursive(s, i, strlen(s) - 1);
}
```

Thanks Richard, that was helpful!

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: `l`, `i`, and `1` all used close together--- **ugh**.  If the ell is supposed to be 'length', then it is used rather strangely.  It could stand for 'last', but that would be inconsistent with common C (buffer/string lengths are much more common).  However, the basic algorithm here is correct, even if wasteful on the termination condition (`i >= l-1`).  (And for reference, this is appropriate as a self-answer because it does answer the question more than comment upon a different answer, but self-answers are usually rare.)

Comment: *len* is now the length of the string minus one (in other words, not the length).  You're down to stylistic, subjective, or minor improvements at this point though (which is a good thing).

Comment: So this version is THE O(n) version of the recursive string reversal? if so then i can move on with the exercises...

Comment: Yes, it is O(n), the Wikipedia page I linked in the comment on the question will explain the basics to you, and I'm sure there's several questions about it on SO too.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly do much better swapping the element on one end with the element on the other end, and advance to the next element. You would then need two parameters: the pointer to the current element and the distance to the other end. The base case is the one with the distance <= 2. That would make your algorithm work in linear time (O(n))

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your code does F(n) operations for an n-length string. Then, from the recursion you wrote we can see that:

> F(2) = 2
>
> F(n) = n + F(n-1) + (n-1)*5 = F(n-1) + 6n - 5

The first 'n' is the strlen, The F(n-1) is the recursive call, and the (n-1)*5 is from the for-loop (the 3 operations, and the "i< l", "i++").

If we open the formula we get:

> F(n) = 6n-5 + 6(n-1)-5 + 6(n-2)-5 + ... + 6*(2)-5 = 6(2+3+4+...+n) - 5*n = 6(n(n+1)/2 -1) - 5n
>
> F(n) = 3n^2 +3n -6 -5n = 3n^2 -2n -6

The last formula is obviously O(n^2).

You don't need recursion to reverse a text. Simple switch every i-char with the (l-i)-char.

```
void switch_chars(char *a, char *b) {
  char temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}
void reverse(char s[]) {
  int l = strlen(s);
  for (int i=0; i<l/2; i++) {
    switch_chars(&s[i], &s[l-1-i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've got to do it recursively. But this was informative aswell, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Actually splitting the problem into functions (and inline functions) might be a good idea.

The algorithm is quite simple, given a string of n characters, you swap the first character with the last character, the second with the last but one and so on until you've swapped every character.

This could be expressed like this in pseudocode:

```
str: string of length n
i <- 0
j <- n - 1

reverse (i, j):
   if i < j:
       swap str[i] and str[j]
       increment i
       decrement j
       reverse(i, j)
```

And this is a possible C implementation with pointers:

```
static inline void swapCharacters (char* a, char* b)
{
    *a += *b;
    *b = *a - *b;
    *a -= *b;
}

static void recursiveReverse (char* left, char* right)
{
    if (left < right) {
        swapCharacters(left, right);
        recursiveReverse(++left, --right);
    }
}

void reverseString (char* string)
{
    char* last = strchr(string, '\0') - 1; // Finds the first character before the terminator
    recursiveReverse(string, last);
}
```

Anyway this won't work if your string is a read-only buffer, for example if you try to do

```
char* string = "My string";
reverseString(string);
```

It will give you a segmentation fault.

So the best solution is actually to dynamically-allocate a buffer in which the reversed string is copied, then the buffer is returned and freed when it's no longer needed.

Comment: The `swapCharacters` function would be clearer and faster using a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside the box.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define REVERSE(STRING) r(*(STRING),(STRING),(STRING)+1)

char *r(char v, char *s, char *n) {
    if (*n && *s) s = r(*n, s, n+1);
    *s = v;
    return s+1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) 
        printf("Usage: RSIP <string to reverse>\n");
    else {
        printf("String to reverse: %s\n", argv[1]);
        REVERSE(argv[1]);
        printf("Reversed string:   %s\n", argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```