# Reversing characters using recursion

Tags: vb.net, string, recursion

I can achieve reversing each word in a string and keep the order as well, but I believe it can be done quicker using recursion. At the moment I'm going through each character and flipping it, its not the best as it can be slow when the string is long. I'm working on an encryption algorithm if you want to know...

Example: 473hTml je31%@31#

This would result to: lmTh374 #13@%13ej

Any guidance or a good read would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate [string reversal recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993247/string-reversal-recursively)

Comment: you take the last character of the word and concatenate the reverse of the rest of the word :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use recursion: it won't be faster. Reversing a string is not a problem that requires recursion.

Actually, VB.Net has a [`StrReverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e462ax87.aspx) function, so I would advise you to just use that (combine with `String.Split` to break your string into words, and `String.Join` to put them back together).

Also, [don't roll your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) - at least, not for protecting anything serious.

Comment: "don't roll your own crypto" +100

Comment: and there are no problems that **require** recursion

Comment: @Blorgbeard I knew about the strreverse function, thought there would be a better way. Also using split and then join, wouldn't that cause some detrimental affects on speed etc... on another note, I'm not rolling my own encryption rather expanding on the CryptoStream class..

Comment: The StrReverse function is pretty fast. Why do you think there would be a (significantly) better way? If there was, wouldn't microsoft have implemented StrReverse in that way? If I were you, I wouldn't worry about optimizations until you have something working. Then you can see if it's fast enough, and if not, profile it, find the actual slow code, and try to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no vb expert, but something like this should be a good start.

```
public string reverseWord(string data) {
    if (data.length == 1) {
        return data;
    } else {
        return data.Concat(data.Substring(-1), reverseWord(data.Substring(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Behold, the recursive BogoFlip!

```
Module Module1
    Private rnd As New Random
    Dim str As String = "testing"

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(str & "     " & BogoFlip(str))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Function BogoFlip(originalString As String) As String
        Dim copy As String = originalString
        Dim flipped As String = ""
        Do Until copy.Length = 0
            Dim index As Integer = rnd.Next(copy.Length)
            flipped &= copy(index)
            copy = copy.Remove(index, 1)
        Loop
        If flipped = StrReverse(originalString) Then
            Return flipped
        Else
            Return BogoFlip(originalString)
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

Please don't do this in real life... please please please please.

Comment: I was amused by the question, I figured I would share my amusement.